# How to use mongoose custom validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a mongoose schema that I want to validate. What I want to do is to check for whenever the age is present, then birthYear cannot be empty. I have tried both the required and validate property but it isn't working :(

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const person = new mongoose.Schema({
  age: { type: Number },
  birthYear: { 
     type: String,
     required: function () {
        return this.age&& !this.age.length;
      },
      validate: [validates, 'Cannot be empty']
  },
  fullName: { type: String }
})

function validates(value) {
  return this.age && !value;
}
```

Comment: your `age` is type number so `return this.age` or `return this.age != null` would be enough.

Comment: If it was a string, will there be a different type of check? @CuongLeNgoc